# data loading in UITableView like in iBooks search table

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

How can I tell UITableView to re-render itself when I add some new data?
I am executing this code ib loadView method.

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(addSomeData) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

This is addSomeData method:

```
-(void)addSomeData{

NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    [myArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Page %i",i]];
    NSDate *d2 = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.2f];
    [NSThread sleepUntilDate:d2];
}

[pool release];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

NSString *string = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = string;
// Configure the cell...
return cell;
}
```

myArray ist is NSArray which contains string.
SO the main question is - how to dynamically update tableview when I add new NSString to myArray?

Answer (score 1):

`[self.tableView reloadData]` method is one solution that completly reload the table and `[self.tableView insertRowAtIndexPath:withAnimation]` is another that only insert the new row and animates the change.

Answer (score 0):

Try : `[self.tableView reloadData];`